# How to update JSON column with new attribute value?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, sql-update, oracle12c

I have a situation where I need to update json column dynamically in my table. See structure below

```
create table tjson ( jsoncol CLOB CONSTRAINT tjson_chk CHECK (jsoncol IS JSON) );    

insert into tjson (jsoncol) VALUES ( '{"name" : "Kunal", "LName" : "Vohra" , 
                                       "salary" : "10000", "Age" : "25"}');

insert into tjson (jsoncol) VALUES ( '{"name" : "Rahul", "LName" : "Sharma" , 
                                       "salary" : "20000", "Age" : "35"}');
```

Now I need to change `salary` to a dynamic value for complete table on the basis of `some_condition`

I can read data using `JSON_VALUE(jsoncol, '$.Age')`

```
update tjson 
   set jsoncol = '"salary":$JustChangeSalary' 
 where some_condition;
```

salary is dynamic and not fixed. I am willing to change just salary.

I tried `json_mergepatch` but that is available only from `Oracle version 19`. We are using `Oracle version 12.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to update the salary of Kunal to 15000, then use `JSON_EXISTS()` function in the WHERE condition to bring the record of him only, and use traditional `REPLACE()` function next to the SET clause with the literal excerpt containing key-value combinations related to `salary` as

```
UPDATE tjson 
   SET jsoncol = REPLACE( jsoncol, '"salary" : "10000"', '"salary" : "15000"' )
 WHERE JSON_EXISTS(jsoncol, '$.name?(@ == "Kunal")');
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e28f4b2e3e76d41dde27f7aaaac7937a)</kbd>

Comment: it failed. SQL Error: ORA-40442: JSON path expression syntax error
@Barbaros Özhan

Comment: the problem is related to a bug. It runs within 12c also. Consult your admin and tell that he needs to *apply the latest JSON patch bundle which includes the fix for bug.18999568 (see Note.1992767.1 for patch number reference)* @KunalVohra .

Comment: Thanks @Barbaros Özhan. In the mean I have asked one more question related to oracle DB script, can you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61949262/convert-select-oracle-query-to-updte-for-specific-scenario

Answer (score 5):

Before `json_mergepatch` you can use basic string functions like `replace`.

But you need to take care with these - formatting differences may cause these to fail. It's also possible you can update multiple attributes which match your criteria.

You can do safely in pure SQL by:

- Converting the JSON object to rows-and-columns with `json_table`
- Reconstructing the document with `json_object(agg)` and `json_array(agg)`, passing the new values as needed.

For example:

```
create table tjson ( 
  jsoncol CLOB CONSTRAINT tjson_chk CHECK (jsoncol IS JSON) 
);

insert into tjson (jsoncol) VALUES ( 
  '{"name" : "Kunal", "LName" : "Vohra" , "salary" : "10000", "Age" : "25"}'
);

insert into tjson (jsoncol) VALUES ( 
  '{"name" : "Rahul", "LName" : "Sharma" , "salary" : "20000", "Age" : "35"}'
);

commit;

select json_object (
  'name' value j.name,
  'LName' value j.LName,
  'salary' value 30000, -- put new salary here
  'Age' value j.Age
) 
from   tjson, json_table (
  jsoncol, '$'
  columns (
    name path '$.name',
    LName path '$.LName',
    Age int path '$.Age'
  )
) j
where  j.name = 'Kunal';

JSON_OBJECT('NAME'VALUEJ.NAME,'LNAME'VALUEJ.LNAME,'SALARY'VALUE30000,--PUTNEWSALARYHERE'AGE'VALUEJ.AGE)   
{"name":"Kunal","LName":"Vohra","salary":30000,"Age":25}  

select t.jsoncol.name, t.jsoncol.salary
from   tjson t;

NAME    SALARY   
Kunal    10000     
Rahul    20000     


update tjson t
set    jsoncol = (
  select json_object (
    'name' value j.name,
    'LName' value j.LName,
    'salary' value 30000, -- put new salary here
    'Age' value j.Age
  ) 
  from   tjson, json_table (
    jsoncol, '$'
    columns (
      name path '$.name',
      LName path '$.LName',
      Age int path '$.Age'
    )
  ) j
  where t.jsoncol.name = j.name
)
where t.jsoncol.name = 'Kunal';

select t.jsoncol.name, t.jsoncol.salary
from   tjson t;

NAME    SALARY   
Kunal    30000     
Rahul    20000
```

Clearly this is... cumbersome! It's impractical for complex documents.

Luckily from 12.2 you can manipulate a JSON document using PL/SQL object types:

```
declare
  jdoc tjson.jsoncol%type;
  jobj json_object_t;
begin
  select t.jsoncol
  into   jdoc
  from   tjson t
  where  t.jsoncol.name = 'Kunal';

  jobj := json_object_t.parse ( jdoc );
  jobj.put ( 'salary', 40000 );
  jdoc := jobj.to_clob();

  update tjson t
  set    jsoncol = jdoc
  where  t.jsoncol.name = 'Kunal';
end;
/

select t.jsoncol.name, t.jsoncol.salary
from   tjson t;

NAME    SALARY   
Kunal    40000     
Rahul    20000
```