# Convert Select Oracle Query To Updte for specific scenario

Tags: database, oracle, updates, oracle12c, insert-update

we are using **Oracle v12+**

we have a situation where we need to update `status` **column to previous value** whenever we have first `RENEWAL` for every `code` (it is functional ID and has many rows against one ID) otherwise `ADD`.

See sample i/o below. Data is sorted by timestamp for each ID.

Do we need specific joins to update? I have copied data to temp table for that but not getting success.

Table name: **`table_book_status`**

```
     Input                           CLOB
    [code]        [word]         [status]                               [timestamp]
    B000JMLBHU  book    {"name" : "Kunal", "type" : "RENEWAL"}
    B000JMLBHU  read    {"name" : "Kunal", "type" : "RENEWAL"}
    B000JMLBHU  was     {"name" : "Kunal", "type" : "MODIFY"}
    B000JMLBHU  story   {"name" : "Kunal", "type" : "ADD"}
    B000R93D4Y  with    {"name" : "RAHUL", "type" : "RENEWAL"}
    B000R93D4Y  book    {"name" : "RAHUL", "type" : "RENEWAL"}
    B000R93D4Y  story   {"name" : "RAHUL", "type" : "RENEWAL"}
    B000R93D4Y  was     {"name" : "RAHUL", "type" : "MODIFY"}
    B000R93D4Y  have    {"name" : "RAHUL", "type" : "ADD"}
    B001892DGG  was     {"name" : "Kanav", "type" : "ADD"}
    B001892DWA  was     {"name" : "Kavita", "type" : "ADD"}
    B001BXNQ2O  was     {"name" : "Keshav", "type" : "RENEWAL"}
    B001BXNQ2O  book    {"name" : "Keshav", "type" : "RENEWAL"}
    B001H55R8M  was     {"name" : "Raghav", "type" : "MODIFY"}
    B001HQHCBQ  was     {"name" : "RINA", "type" : "ADD"}
    B001HQHCBQ  story   {"name" : "RINA", "type" : "ADD"}
    B001HQHCBQ  bella   {"name" : "RINA", "type" : "ADD"}
    B001HQHCBQ  with    {"name" : "RINA", "type" : "ADD"}
    B001HQHCBQ  love    {"name" : "RINA", "type" : "ADD"}
    B001HQHCBQ  zsadist {"name" : "RINA", "type" : "ADD"}


    Output


   [code]        [word]              [status]                               [timestamp]
    B000JMLBHU  book    {"name" : "Kunal", "type" : "RENEWAL"}
    B000JMLBHU  read    {"name" : "Kunal", "type" : "**MODIFY**"}
    B000JMLBHU  was     {"name" : "Kunal", "type" : "MODIFY"}
    B000JMLBHU  story   {"name" : "Kunal", "type" : "ADD"}
    B000R93D4Y  with    {"name" : "RAHUL", "type" : "RENEWAL"}
    B000R93D4Y  book    {"name" : "RAHUL", "type" : "RENEWAL"}
    B000R93D4Y  story   {"name" : "RAHUL", "type" : "**MODIFY**"}
    B000R93D4Y  was     {"name" : "RAHUL", "type" : "MODIFY"}
    B000R93D4Y  have    {"name" : "RAHUL", "type" : "ADD"}
    B001892DGG  was     {"name" : "Kanav", "type" : "ADD"}
    B001892DWA  was     {"name" : "Kavita", "type" : "ADD"}
    B001BXNQ2O  was     {"name" : "Keshav", "type" : "RENEWAL"}
    B001BXNQ2O  book    {"name" : "Keshav", "type" : "**ADD**"}
    B001H55R8M  was     {"name" : "Raghav", "type" : "MODIFY"}
    B001HQHCBQ  was     {"name" : "RINA", "type" : "ADD"}
    B001HQHCBQ  story   {"name" : "RINA", "type" : "ADD"}
    B001HQHCBQ  bella   {"name" : "RINA", "type" : "ADD"}
    B001HQHCBQ  with    {"name" : "RINA", "type" : "ADD"}
    B001HQHCBQ  love    {"name" : "RINA", "type" : "ADD"}
    B001HQHCBQ  zsadist {"name" : "RINA", "type" : "ADD"}
```

With the help of stackOverflow community we were able to create a select query

```
    SELECT code,
  status,
  CASE
    WHEN sm    = 1
    AND status = 'RENEWAL'
    THEN COALESCE(lgst, 'ADD')
    ELSE status
  END AS status1,
  timestamp
FROM
  (SELECT code,
    JSON_VALUE(status, '$.type') AS status,
    SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN JSON_VALUE(status, '$.type') = 'RENEWAL'
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END) over (partition BY code order by timestamp)                                              AS sm,
    lag(JSON_VALUE(status, '$.type')) over (partition BY code order by timestamp) AS lgst,
    timestamp
  FROM table_book_status
  );
```

This is giving perfect result as needed but in select view, we want to get that converted to `UPDATE` oracle query or maybe `PL/SQL`. Any suggestion on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great way to update a table from a query is to use a MERGE statement.  Here is an example that copies all_objects and adds a column of the number of objects that match that rows owner and type.

```
CREATE TABLE all_objects_2 AS
SELECT *
  FROM all_objects;

ALTER TABLE all_objects_2 add owner_and_type_ct NUMBER;

MERGE INTO all_objects_2 ao2
USING (SELECT ao.owner,
              ao.object_type,
              COUNT(*) AS ct
         FROM all_objects ao
        GROUP BY ao.owner,
                 ao.object_type) x
ON (ao2.owner = x.owner AND ao2.object_type = x.object_type)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
     SET ao2.owner_and_type_ct = x.ct;

SELECT ao2.owner,
       ao2.object_name,
       ao2.object_type,
       ao2.owner_and_type_ct
  FROM all_objects_2 ao2
 WHERE rownum < 10;
/*
SYS C_TS# CLUSTER 10
SYS I_TS# INDEX 1459
SYS C_FILE#_BLOCK#  CLUSTER 10
SYS I_FILE#_BLOCK#  INDEX 1459
SYS FET$  TABLE 1592
SYS UET$  TABLE 1592
SYS SEG$  TABLE 1592
SYS UNDO$ TABLE 1592
SYS TS$ TABLE 1592
*/
```

You MERGE INTO [destination table] USING [your query] ON [criteria to join query to destination] and WHEN you MATCH a row you UPDATE the row with the values from the query.  You can also INSERT and DELETE with a MERGE, but I'm not going to duplicate all the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9017.htm#SQLRF01606).